# How do I skip a script in Python depending on the value returned from a request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am writing a script in Python that uses requests to get `uid` fields from an api. The `uid` retrieved is to be used as part of a second url where another request is to be made. When the `uid` is inserted into the second url, a list is supposed to be returned which I then iterate over and extract some data. The only problem is that some requests to the new url return an empty list which then throws an error when I try to iterate over. Here is the code:

```
taxon_url = f"https://records-ws.nbnatlas.org/occurrences/search?q=data_resource_uid:{uid}&fq=taxon_concept_lsid:*&facets=taxon_concept_lsid&pageSize=0&flimit=-1"
taxon_response = requests.get(taxon_url)
json_response = taxon_response.json()

jsonpath_expr = parse('$..facetResults[*].fieldResult[*]')
resources = [ match.value for match in jsonpath_expr.find(json_response) ]

for label in resources:
    taxon_id = label['label']
    print(taxon_id)
```

So, as I mentioned, the `resources` returned should be a list which in some cases in an empty list and this throws the `local variable referenced before assignment even though it is explicitly assigned` error for `taxon_id` for the next part of the script:

```
class_url = f"https://species-ws.nbnatlas.org/species/{taxon_id}"
class_response = requests.get(class_url)
class_json = class_response.json()
```

Your assistance is highly appreciated

Comment: Use an `if` statement to check that you have what you expect before you pass it on to the next request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the length of the resources list is grater than 0 like:

```
taxon_url = f"https://records-ws.nbnatlas.org/occurrences/search?q=data_resource_uid:{uid}&fq=taxon_concept_lsid:*&facets=taxon_concept_lsid&pageSize=0&flimit=-1"
taxon_response = requests.get(taxon_url)
json_response = taxon_response.json()

jsonpath_expr = parse('$..facetResults[*].fieldResult[*]')
resources = [ match.value for match in jsonpath_expr.find(json_response) ]
if len(resources) > 0:
  for label in resources:
     taxon_id = label['label']
     print(taxon_id)
```

Or you can also use a try-except.

Answer (score 0):

if your resources list is empty, the code block under the for loop won't assign taxon_id. So you should define a default value for taxon_id variable for printing/using it without errors. Or you can always check if the list is empty or use try/except.